# Using calculated values such as MAX inside a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table (student_lesson_progress):

- Id
- lessonId
- studentId
- lessonStatusTypeId
- recordDateTime
- ...

I need to capture the number of students in the current school year whose last status was either of two values (6 or 13).

I'm an SQL novice. I think I want to start by getting the last record for each studentId/lessonId combination. Then I want to narrow that list down to those that meet my criteria. This is the query that I think I want but it triggers a syntax error at "Max" in the subquery.

```
SELECT M1.*  
FROM student_lesson_progress M1  
{  
SELECT MAX(id) as lastRecord, lessonId, studentId, lessonStatusTypeId  
FROM student_lesson_progress  
GROUP BY studentId, lessonId  
} M2  
WHERE recordDateTime > "2012-08-01" 
AND (lessonStatusTypeId = 13 or lessonStatusTypeId = 6)  
ORDER BY studentId, lessonId, lastRecord
```

I'm having difficulty finding an example of syntax for subqueries with calculated values. Suggestions? Or maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're just missing a join between `M1` and `M2`

```
SELECT COUNT(M1.StudentID) AS Students
FROM student_lesson_progress M1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) as lastRecord, lessonId, studentId, lessonStatusTypeId  
     FROM student_lesson_progress  
     GROUP BY studentId, lessonId) M2 ON M1.ID = M2.lastRecord -- need to join M1 and M2 together
WHERE recordDateTime > '2012-08-01'
AND (lessonStatusTypeId = 13 or lessonStatusTypeId = 6)
ORDER BY studentId, lessonId, lastRecord
```

Answer (score 0):

If IDs are always increasing, you could use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM student_lesson_progress
WHERE
  id IN (SELECT max(id)
         FROM student_lesson_progress
         GROUP BY studentId, lessonId)
  AND recordDateTime > '2012-08-01'
  AND lessonStatusTypeId IN (13, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks, these have both been very helpful. Here's the final syntax I've got:

Comment: Very helpful. However, I still have a problem. The MAX command is giving me the correct value but only for that field.
RecordDateTime  lessonId  studentId lessonStatusTypeId
2013-03-01 21:27:00 14   293  1
2013-03-02 21:27:00 14   293  8
2013-03-03 21:27:00 14   293  4

I'm expecting:
2013-03-03 21:27:00 14   293  4

what I'm getting:
2013-03-03 21:27:00 14   293  1

I've got the last date/time but the lessonStatusTypeId seems to come from the first record, not the last. This seems wrong. How does one generalize the MAX command to get information from the entire record and not just that field?